# C# input values for GradeBook

Tags: c#

I created this Gradebook code sometime ago. I learned to write it from watching videos and such while learning C#.

Inserting a grade into the Gradebook is successful when the input grade is hardcoded. I am trying to update the code so that I can input a grade from the console window rather than the grade being hardcoded.

The following code is what I have so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        //synth.Speak("Welcome, to the Grade Book Program.");

        //SpeechSynthesizer justMoreToSay = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        //justMoreToSay.Speak("Okay, Now that we got that out of the way. May you input the Grades please.");


        /*Gradebook book = new Gradebook();
        book.AddGrade(91);
        book.AddGrade(89);
        book.AddGrade(83.5f);
        book.AddGrade(78);
        book.AddGrade(98);
        book.AddGrade(93);
        book.AddGrade(79);
        book.AddGrade(64);
        book.AddGrade(32);
        book.AddGrade(45);
        book.AddGrade(67);
        book.AddGrade(90);
        book.AddGrade(58);
        book.AddGrade(72);
        book.AddGrade(100);
        book.AddGrade(85);*/

        Console.WriteLine("Please go ahead and Listen to the Voice and input the Grades:");

        Gradebook inputValues = new Gradebook();
        inputValues.AddGrade(85);
        inputValues.AddGrade(62);        


        GradeStatistics stats = inputValues.ComputeStatistics();
        //Console.WriteLine(stats.HighestGrade);
        //Console.WriteLine(stats.AverageGrade);
        //Console.WriteLine(stats.LowestGrade);
        Console.WriteLine("The average for this person is {0} and the Highest grade he made is {1} and the Lowest is {2}. If you May please select any character to exit the program!", stats.AverageGrade, stats.HighestGrade, stats.LowestGrade);

}
}
```

---

```
public class Gradebook
{

    public Gradebook()
    {
        grades = new List<float>();
    }

    public GradeStatistics ComputeStatistics()
    {
        GradeStatistics stats = new GradeStatistics();

        float sum = 0;
        foreach (float grade in grades)
        {
            {
                stats.HighestGrade = Math.Max(grade, stats.HighestGrade);
                stats.LowestGrade = Math.Min(grade, stats.LowestGrade);

                sum = sum + grade;                   
            }
        }
        stats.AverageGrade = sum / grades.Count;
        return stats;
    }

    public void AddGrade(float grade)
    {
        grades.Add(grade);
    }

    public List<float> grades;      
}
```

Comment: It's Working fine. But I am wanting to make it where i input the Values form the console.Window.

Comment: Why are you using a float for a grade(Most grade systems have multiple points per answer, so there is no need for a partial or a .5.)? I would probably change that to a long, and you could save some time by using static classes. Also, just loop shachaf said and I would use; bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number); to make sure you get valid data.

Comment: You are looking for something like: `var grade = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` ?

Answer (score 0):

To read line from console and convert it to integer you can use read line and convert the string to numeric representation:

```
Console.Writeline("Enter Number");

var num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

you do this in a loop until you receive some sort of terminating input from the user, for example `-1`

Comment: I have tried that, but you only can input one grade. I want to make it where i input like 10 grades. Would i use a Array?

Comment: you have a list already inside Gradebook, just insert that input num into the the GradeBook, also look at my answer this should be done inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int num =10;//
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
Console.Writeline("Enter grade");
inputValues.AddGrade(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```